# How add condition in trigger?

Tags: mysql

I have query for crete trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `Insert` AFTER INSERT ON `HistoryBalance`
 FOR EACH ROW INSERT INTO Winners (name) VALUES  (new.ProductID)
```

But now i woul like get condition:

```
if (new.Status = 'user'){
   CREATE TRIGGER `Insert` AFTER INSERT ON `Balance`
 FOR EACH ROW INSERT INTO Winners (name) VALUES  (new.ProductID)
}
```

Tell me please how right crete trigger with my condition ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
delimiter $$
CREATE TRIGGER balance_insert AFTER INSERT ON Balance
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    if (new.Status = 'user') then
        INSERT INTO Winners(name) VALUES  (new.ProductID);
    end if;
END; $$
delimiter ;
```

You can read more [Here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html)

Comment: on **[this trigger](http://pastebin.com/i7zDFQDF)** we are get error `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'end if;
END' at line 8 ` Can are you check it ?

Comment: You might need a semicolon at the end of the `insert`.